# calling object members - javascript

Tags: javascript

If i have:

```
var obj={
    a:function(){obj.b();},
    b:function(){this.a();}
};
```

is there any difference in calling object methods with "this" or referring directly to the object itself because it is on the same scope as the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends

`this` can take many forms, making it unpredictable:

- In a normal function call, like `funcName()`, `this` is the global object. In browsers, it's the `window` object.
- In a normal function call where the function uses "use strict", `this` is `undefined`.
- For a function used as a constructor, like `var instance = new ConstructorFunction()`, `this` will refer to the instance object created from that constructor.
- For object literals, `this` is the immediate object literal enclosing the function.
- When called by `call(context,args...)` or `apply(context,[args...])`, `this` is whatever `context` is.

Answer (score 2):

`this` can change depending on how you call the function:

```
var funnyB = obj.b;
funnyB();  //this is window
```

Answer (score 0):

In the object literal context that you provided, there is no logical difference.  The `this` keyword points to the `obj` variable, since `this` is a reference to the object that the function is a property/method of.